# XSLT transform doesn't recognize attribute of parent node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

.Net XSLT parser doesn't recognize parent attribute (type) if there is child to that node (contributor).   returns empty for following scenario but returns correct result if I remove child node.

**Input XML**

```
<contributors>
  <roles>
    <role type="Actor">
      <contributor />
    </role>
  </roles>
</contributors>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <a>
      <xsl:value-of select="contributors/roles/role/@type" />
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<a></a>
```

My C# method

```
    public static XDocument TransformXML(string inputXMLString, string xslt)
    {
        var xmlDocumentWithoutNs = RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement.Parse(inputXMLString));
        inputXMLString = xmlDocumentWithoutNs.ToString();

        var xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xslt))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
        {
            xslCompiledTransform.Load(xmlReader);
        }
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(inputXMLString))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xslCompiledTransform.Transform(xmlReader, new XsltArgumentList(), stringWriter);
            var resultXML = stringWriter.ToString();
            var otuput = XDocument.Parse(resultXML);
            return otuput;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What child node do you mean to "remove" ? Where do you see a "parent attribute" ?

Comment: works ok with contributor child node in xalanj and xsltproc, strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without removing the NS. Its working for me :-)

```
var xmlDocumentWithoutNs = XElement.Parse(inputXMLString);
```

Comment: Thanks Aishu.. Looks like I need to fix my method to remove namespaces